# Top Network Askers are wrong?

Tags: bug, stack-exchange

I recently noticed the "Top Network Askers" information at the right side when i call my default link to my newest favorite-tags on Stack Overflow:

https://stackexchange.com/filters/341093/favorite-tags?sort=newest

But this can't be correct because those users have asked very few questions with no upvotes like [JayMac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9947028/jaymac). Maybe i have misunderstood it though.

[image]

**Update**: it seems that this list always repeats the same order in which the questions appear that are listed on the left side. The users on the right side are the OP's of the questions of the left side. You can see it also on https://stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Where is that list? I've never seen that on any of the question list pages.

Comment: @KevinB: added the URL

Comment: *"These users asked the most up-voted questions **on this page**"*

Comment: @Tim pay attention to 'On this page' part, I assume the list is just from the questions listed

Comment: @KevinB: well, the page is StackOverflow, isn't it? You saw the link in the question to [JayMac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9796182/john-v)?

Comment: Yeh if you look at the users and their questions there's obviously something wrong. It looks like it's literally just listing the users on that page (in the same order the questions appear)

Comment: It's the same on https://stackexchange.com/ too, it literally just lists (in order) the users who asked the questions on that page

Comment: @Cai: in what order? I cant recognize any order or logic.

Comment: @Tim the same order the questions appear on the page (you can even see it in your screenshot)

Comment: @Cai: you're right. This list is definitely a bug. It just repeats the same order of the question list that you are watching which has nothing to do with the top-network-users.

Comment: Indeed, it's either a bug... or a badly labelled and totally useless list

Answer (score 4):

On [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) which lists *Hot Network Questions*:

1. the gravatars appear to be wrong (might be related to the [*Great Firewall of China*](https://www.howtogeek.com/162092/htg-explains-how-the-great-firewall-of-china-works/) or maybe there's dubious Internet where I am)
2. the list changes depending on which page you are on
3. a user can appear multiple times
4. there's no reason to re-list the users

[image]

Since *Hot Network Questions* are now tracked, I feel it'd be sensible to replace it with the users who have asked the most *Hot Network Questions*.

Comment: What is a "China thing?"

Comment: I see the same Gravatar for you on that page and not your cetacean so it is not the Chinese internet which is causing this

Comment: @mdewey true, the Gravatar on se.com for Rebecca missing email hash, so it's the default identicon. Maybe after synch it will fix itself, dunno.

Comment: can reproduce, half the avatars are the same as on screenshot, duplicates also exist. Maybe duplicate users should list all the sites they have under their name instead of having an entry per site?